# Command to find files for a specific time range

Tags: command-line, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a few Linux Red Hat Linux machines and I must find some files on them. The problem is that they have a lot of files and folders since 2004 year. And I don't know where exactly to look for these files.

Is there some terminal command with which I can select a specific time range. I want to see every file which is changed from last month (May) to now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the `find` command can do this. It will take some experimentation and reading and re-reading the man page to get it to do what you want, but is amazing command. Below are 2 examples:

```
find . -type f -ctime -2 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rvf ~/dev_customer_attributes.tar
find . -mmin -400 > /tmp/files.txt
```

The 1st `find` uses `-type f` to list only files. `-type d` for directories. `-ctime -2` is for files with a created time less than 2 days old and then adds them to the tar archive. *I can't remember from when I used this command or why*.

The 2nd command checks for files and directories modified within the last 400 days and outputs that list to `files.txt` [Here's a great info page I just found, too](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html).

---

Example, In my ~ on my personal laptop are files as old as 2010. And lots that are newer, too. By running `find . -ctime -1000 -ctime +600`, I get listing like this:

```
./Pictures/Photos
./Pictures/Photos/2005
./Pictures/Photos/2005/08
./Pictures/Photos/2005/08/29
./Pictures/Photos/2005/08/29/DSCN1023.JPG
./Pictures/Photos/2009
./Pictures/Photos/2009/02
./Pictures/Photos/2009/02/23
./Pictures/Photos/2009/02/23/img_0001.jpg
./Pictures/Photos/2010
./Pictures/Photos/2010/01
./Pictures/Photos/2010/01/01
./Pictures/Photos/2010/01/01/DSCN2170.JPG
./Pictures/Photos/2010/01/01/DSCN2171.JPG
./Pictures/Photos/2010/06
./Pictures/Photos/2010/06/04
./Pictures/Photos/2010/06/04/img_0111.jpg
./Pictures/Photos/2010/06/04/img_0112.jpg
./Pictures/Webcam/2010-10-03-045227.jpg
./.mission-control
./.mission-control/accounts
./.mission-control/accounts/accounts.cfg
```

In this case, the `Pictures` folder had legacy items copied over from before 2010, but which happened with the 400 day period 600 days ago.

Comment: But i don't know in witch folder and what file exactly i looking for. I mean that's why i need to see witch file were modified last 30 days in whole system.

Comment: Yes, so move to /, omit the `-type` look for `-ctime` of `-` 8 years of days and another `-ctime` of something like `+` 4 years in days. This will list all folders and files which meet the time criteria. Editing answer to show example...

Comment: this work I just need to write correct time range

Comment: 8 years is 2920 days, just figure out the "new" cutoff date. I just wing it with size of the output. I also use `wc` to see how many lines of text a command returns to see the size of it. You could do -3000 +2000 and move the +2000 up or down from there.

Comment: Might want to use `-print0` with find and `xargs -0` in order to be safe.

Comment: It should be `mtime` instead of `ctime` if you want find files which CONTENT was changed. At this point `ctime` is changed, too - but not only than, so this could result in a missleading list. See this wonderful explanation about `ctime`, `mtime` and `atime`: http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime

Comment: @JimmyKoerting in reading the comments to another answer, `mtime` didn't work for the OP but `ctime` did.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ man find

find . -name '*.doc' -type f -mtime -28
```

Lists all .doc-Files below (and in) the current directory that have an 'mtime' (modify date) newer than 28 days.

Comment: I believe -28 means newer than 28 days.

Comment: You're correct. I fixed this. Just switched the words.

Answer (score 2):

[find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) is what you are looking for

> find . -newermt "2012-05-01 00:00:00"

This will give you a list of files that match.
You can add the `-ls` flag for more information. Like this

> find . -newermt "2012-05-01 00:00:00" -ls

Comment: find: invalid predicate `-newermt' this i get

Comment: well I'm connected right now with putty to server

Comment: @JasonPaddle - If you can't get the `-newermt`flag to work I suggest you use `-mtime -28` instead (as suggested elsewhere). It will give the same result but require you to do the maths (so if you run it tomorrow it will be `-mtime -29` and so on).

Comment: with -mtime i get only one result. One file from today witch is modified  1 hour ago: find . -mtime -28 -ls

Comment: @JasonPaddle - Are you invoking the command in the correct location? Can you manually find a file that the command missed?

Comment: with -ctime i got the results

Comment: @JasonPaddle - Another thing, `find` does not follow symbolic links by default. Try adding the `-follow` flag.

Comment: @JasonPaddle - Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need the -mtime parameter of the find command. See if this is any help:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/