# Linux find files that differ from a given date

Tags: linux, find, date

i would like to search for file that has not a give date.

for example i want to find in my server all file created before 2015-12-01 o after

any suggestion ?

thanks

luca

refer also to [Command to find files for specific time range](https://superuser.com/questions/442490/command-to-find-files-for-specific-time-range)

Comment: There's a difference between _not having a given timestamp_ and _having a timestamp smaller than a given timestamp_. Since you already found `find`, I suggest you read the man page first, try something, and get back with a specific question if soemthing doesn't work for you.

Comment: dude, in the man there is not the answer.

my question is still short and specific

how to list in a linux server all file with time stamp different to a given date

Comment: @luca you may start with sharing what you had tried.. that share us the error-message/not-so-wanted-results/printscreen of the trial outcome.. It's a nice way to start looking for help.

Answer (score -1):

Found

```
find . -newermt "20151202" ! -not -newermt "20151203" -ls
```

this will find  all file in all dirs with date different from 12-03-2015

Comment: All files or all files and folders?  (In which case you want to add a -type f).